# Importing an excel spreadsheet to SQL server

Tags: sql, excel

I am having as issue trying to import a file called, Clean_info241 data.xlsx in SQL

It is located in: H:\New_folder  and is on a server

The excel version is 2013, and I DON'T want to use the import wizard.

The goal is to be able to have a one click execute where it creates the database, uses the data from the spreadsheet, and imputs it into a table. I have tried many ways without any luck and have only used the import wizard so far. 
All other code is written. 
The Data is on 2 tabs in excel called johnKey$ and davidcunliffe$

Answer (score 0):

I  think you can do it using a c# app.

Let's say your excel sheet like this.

**ID      Name       Age**

1     Sahan       28

2     Varanga    26

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //You have to add it to reference and to add it to       reference you have to install Office package in your pc which runs the application or you can download this from Microsot

namespace ExcelImport
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string filePath = @"H:\New_folder\<YOUR FILE NAME>";
            string filePath = @"E:\Test.xlsx";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            var missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, false, true, missing, missing, missing, true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, '\t', false, false, 0, false, true, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //Here we say which tabs going to insert into database

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange; //Get only worked range in excel sheet
            Array myValues = (Array)xlRange.Cells.Value2;

           int vertical = myValues.GetLength(0);
           int horizontal = myValues.GetLength(1);

           System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

            // must start with index = 1
            // get header information
            for (int i = 1; i <= horizontal; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(myValues.GetValue(1, i).ToString()));
            }


            // Get the row information
            for (int a = 2; a <= vertical; a++)
            {
                object val = myValues.GetValue(a, 1);
                if (val != null)
                {
                    object[] poop = new object[horizontal];
                    for (int b = 1; b <= horizontal; b++)
                    {
                        object colVal = null;
                        poop[b - 1] = colVal = myValues.GetValue(a, b);
                    }
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = poop;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string id = row["ID"].ToString();
                string Name = row["Name"].ToString();
                string Age = row["Age"].ToString();

                string connectionString = "your connection string";

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();

                StringBuilder insertQry = new StringBuilder();
                insertQry.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO YourTable(ID,Name,Age) VALUES({0},{1},{2})", id, Name, Age);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQry.ToString(), con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will be help to get a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Wizard and save as SSIS package (DTS if you are using an older version of SQL Server).
Then I'd modify the package so the XLS file name and Sheet name would be variables.

After this you can wrap the execution of this package anyway you want. Be that a WinForms with a button, VB Script, Agent Job or anything else...